# Passing in a "TYPE" to a Generic_Interface type Property

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, ninject

Scratching my bald patch....I have a generic Interface

```
interface IGenericInterface<T>
{
    T GenericTypeProperty {get; set;}
    void PerformService(); 
}
```

I have server classes that implement the generic interface and do some stuff

```
public class ServeRich : IGenericInterface<RichPeople>
{
    RichPeople GenericTypeProperty {get; set;}
    void PerformService() { //Serving the rich } 
}

public class ServePoor : IGenericInterface<PoorPeople>
{
    PoorPeople GenericTypeProperty {get; set;}
    void PerformService() { //Serving the Poor }
}
```

Then I have a Service class as follows that I want to invoke and assign one of the server classes to and invoke PerformService()

```
public class ServeThem
{
    //This is where I am trying to figure out how to do this
    IGenericInterface<T<-??> Server {get; set;}

}
```

I want to eventually create the Service class and invoke the perform service method on Server....something like this

```
main()
{
    ServeThem service= new ServeThem();
    service.Server = new ServePoor(); //This will be resolved by Ninject
    service.Server.PerformService();
}
```

My problem is in `IGenericInterface<T<-??> Server {get; set;}`. I am trying to figure out how to declare `Server` property as a generic interface type that can be assigned an object of a class that implements that interface of a particular type. It seems that for declaring `IGenericInterface<type>`, an actual concrete type has to be mentioned. I tried adding a `passedInType` property and using `typeof(passedInType)` but that throws an exception.

How would I declare a property as a generic interface type? Is this even possible.

Comment: You will probably have to make `ServeThem` generic as well, and use the same `T`.

Comment: I want to keep the instance of 'ServeThem' class ignorant of who they are serving and keep its Server property only as type dependent.

Comment: It seems like your design is over-engineered/overly generic. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Also, avoid using plurals and verbs for class names. Class names should be nouns in singular form.

Comment: For example, couldn't you abstract RichPerson and PoorPerson behind an interface and have your Server serve an IPerson instead?

Comment: I did feel like i was going overboard...in the actual scenario here, rich people and poor people are very very different. In my case, even though they would be implementing IPerson, there'd be no members that'd be common among them. Now when I think about it, I might as well have named the classes RichPeople and SandParticles to make the difference evident.

Comment: When you call `service.Server.PerformService()`, do you actually care what is going on behind the scenes?  If you can separate the concept of performing the service from the concept of what or who the service is performed upon, you might be able to simplify the logic that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [*covariance*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
// T is covariant (i.e. the "out" keyword)
public interface IGenericInterface<out T>
{
    // Check that I removed the setter. T wouldn't be covariantly valid
    // if it could be set... 
    // BTW, this doesn't prevent an implementation to provide a setter.
    T GenericTypeProperty { get; }
    void PerformService(); 
}
```

Now turn your `ServeThem` class to declare the whole property as `IGenericInterface<object>`:

```
public class ServeThem
{
    //This is where I am trying to figure out how to do this
    IGenericInterface<object> Server {get; set;}
}
```

If making read-only the `GenericTypeProperty` property isn't an option, then this approach won't work for you. Anyway, most of the times you can take advantage of variance replacing a setter with a constructor parameter:

```
public class ServeRich : IGenericInterface<RichPeople>
{
    private readonly RichPeople _people;

    public ServerRich(RichPeople people)
    {
        _people = people;
    }

    // C# 6 expression-bodied read-only property
    public RichPeople GenericTypeProperty => _people;
    public void PerformService() { //Serving the rich } 
}
```

Comment: @TankJr. No problem! Today you got a new concept about C#, don't you? ;)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you don't use the `GenericTypeProperty` in your service, so you can move the `PerformService` method to a non-generic interface and use this interface in the Service class

```
interface INonGenericInterface
{
    void PerformService(); 
}

interface IGenericInterface<T>: INonGenericInterface
{
    T GenericTypeProperty {get; set;}
}

public class ServeThem
{
    INonGenericInterface Server {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I initially thought about doing this. Martias' solution worked.